# MIPS lb sw instructions

Tags: assembly, mips

Lets assume that register $t1 has the address 0x10000000 with a value of 0xff000011 and register $t2 has the address 0x10000010 with a value of 0x55555555. The datapath works in "Little Endian" system. We have the next instructions:

```
lb $t0,0($t1)

sw $t0,0($t2)
```

what will be the value at address 0x10000010?

It's a very easy question, but I have some trouble understanding how load/store instructions work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming word-sized values by the given addresses, the answer is 0x00000011. Does that help? Did you read your MIPS manual or whatever resource you have or can find?

Comment: I have the final answer, it is correct. but I want to know how to calculate it. Can Someone draw a memory stack with arrows in order me to understand?

Comment: [The wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) on endianness already has diagrams explaining the relationship between words and individual bytes.